# Perl Loop Conceptualization

Tags: perl

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to attack this problem. I have a file that looks like :

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 a
1 1 1 3 4 4 4 a
1 1 1 4 4 4 2 a
2 2 2 3 3 3 2 b
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 b
```

Which, I want to count how many times the first 3 numbers repeat consecutively. As in I load the data set into perl,  and it will spit out:

```
3
2
```

as the string '1 1 1' was found at the start of a line 3 times in a row, and the string '2 2 2' was found to begin a line 2 times in a row. Either string may appear later in the file, which complicates things. As well, I will not know what the beginning string is either, and it varies.

Honestly, I'm just really confused on how to attack this. If anyone can help conceptualize this/ give me some pseudo-code to help, that would be great.

EDIT: As per Borodins answer, which works perfectly for what I asked. However, if I wanted to print the count plus which letter it is, How could I do that? So far,

```
my ( $inp, $outp) = qw / OUT2 OUTFILE/;

open my $input, '<', $inp or die;
open my $output, '>', $outp or die;

my ($last_key, $count);

while ( <$input> ) {

my $key = join ' ', (split)[0..2];
my $id = join ' ', (split)[7];

if ( defined $last_key and $key eq $last_key ) {
++$count;
}
else {
printf "%s %d $id\n", $last_key, $count if defined $last_key;
$last_key = $key;
$count = 1;
}

printf "%s %d $id\n", $last_key, $count if eof;
}
```

Which gives :

```
1 1 1 3 b
2 2 2 2 b
```

which isn't quite what I'm aiming for.

Thanks!

EDIT2

Got what I wanted working. Oftentimes, all it takes is asking for help to figure it out yourself.

Updated code:

```
my ( $inp, $outp) = qw / OUT2 OUTFILE/;

open my $input, '<', $inp or die;
open my $output, '>', $outp or die;

my ($last_key, $count, $last_id);

while ( <$input> ) {

my $key = join ' ', (split)[0..2];
my $id = join ' ', (split)[7];

if ( defined $last_key and $key eq $last_key ) {
++$count;
}
else {
printf "%s %d $last_id\n", $last_key, $count if defined $last_key;
$last_key = $key;
$count = 1;
$last_id = $id;
}
printf "%s %d $id\n", $last_key, $count if eof;
}
```

on:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 a
1 1 1 3 4 4 4 a
1 1 1 4 4 4 2 a
2 2 2 3 3 3 2 b
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 b
3 3 3 2 5 4 2 c
```

gives:

```
1 1 1 3 a
2 2 2 2 b
3 3 3 1 c
```

Thanks all!

Comment: So only the first three numbers on the line matters? Then you could put them into a hash and update the value if the number of consecutive matches exceeds the current value in the hash...

Comment: no need for a hash @HåkonHægland

Comment: Do solutions need to be in perl?

Comment: `cut -d ' ' -f 1-3 < file | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of forming a key from the first three fields and counting the number of times they occur, printing a line of output whenever the key changes or the end of the file is reached

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($last_key, $count);

while ( <DATA> ) {

  my $key = join ' ', (split)[0..2];

  if ( defined $last_key and $key eq $last_key ) {
    ++$count;
  }
  else {
    printf "%s -> %d\n", $last_key, $count if defined $last_key;
    $last_key = $key;
    $count = 1;
  }

  printf "%s -> %d\n", $last_key, $count if eof;
}

__DATA__
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 a
1 1 1 3 4 4 4 a
1 1 1 4 4 4 2 a
2 2 2 3 3 3 2 b
2 2 2 1 1 1 1 b
3 3 3 1 1 1 1 c
```

#### output

```
1 1 1 -> 3
2 2 2 -> 2
3 3 3 -> 1
```

---

#### Update

To include the final column in the output data, just change

```
my $key = join ' ', (split)[0..2]
```

to

```
my $key = join ' ', (split)[0..2,-1]
```

#### output

```
1 1 1 a -> 3
2 2 2 b -> 2
3 3 3 c -> 1
```

Comment: This works great! However, is there also anyway to make it print the 'a' 'b' 'c' at the end of the line? Ive got 'my $id = join ' ', (split)[7];', but adding that to the printf statement doesn't accurately reflect the value.

Comment: @jcklasseter: I've seen your own fix to do this for yourself. Thank you for making the effort -- many people would be in paralysis until they were given a solution -- but it can be done much more simply. I've updated my solution to explain

Comment: Well, my answer left something to be desired in that it replaced the first match of b with a, but that wasn't too hard to work around. Do you have any idea as to why it would work like that? I appreciate it, nonetheless.

Comment: @jcklasseter: Yes; the program works by printing the information about the *previous* block whenever the key changes. It prints `$last_key` and `$count` correctly, but `$id` is taken from the most recent line with the new key so it belongs to the next block. You would need to maintain and print a `$last_id` in the same way as the `$last_key`, but my fix gets around this by just including the ID column in the key

Answer (score 2):

You just have to keep track of the previous line, or at least the relevant part of it, and how many times it was seen:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $count = 0;
my $last_prefix = '';
my $last_value = '';
while (my $line = <>) {
    my ($prefix, $value) = $line =~ /^(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+).*(\S+)/ or die "malformed line $line";
    if ($prefix ne $last_prefix) {
        if ($count) {
            print "$count $last_value\n";
        }
        $last_prefix = $prefix;
        $last_value = $value;
        $count = 0;
    }
    ++$count;
}
if ($count) {
    print "$count $last_value\n";
}
```

Comment: What if a same sequence appear later in the file? For instance `1 1 1` repeat 3 times in the beginning of the file, but 5 five times at the end of the file..

Comment: the question asks for the number of times _consecutively_.  if it appears later in the file, that is a new occurrence.  so, not only is a hash not needed, but it gives the wrong result too.

Comment: I would interpret `"How many times  the first 3 numbers repeat consecutively"` as `"The maximum number of consecutive repetitions"`

Comment: That's certainly a valid reading but not the one I would assume by default.

Comment: modified to add the a/b/c (from the last line of a group) as requested in the comments to Borodin's answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
# Open file and loop through lines
open (INFH, '<', "num.txt");
my $count = 0;
my $str;

my %countHash;

while(<INFH>){
    # split the line using space characters to get first three numbers
    my @numArray = split(' ', $_);

    #Concatenating first three numbers as a string to use as key
    $key = "$numArray[0]" . "$numArray[1]" . "$numArray[2]";

    #If the combination exists, update the value by adding 1. Else add new

    if (!exists $countHash{$key}){
        $countHash{$key} = 1;
    }else{
        $countHash{$key} += 1;
    }
}

print %countHash;
```

I will update if I can make it any better.

Comment: As ysth indicated in the comment on the post you don't need to keep a count for more than the current prefix. You just print the current count as soon as you see the next prefix.

Comment: Guess me and Hakon missed the "Consecutive" part. Let the person who asked clarify "Either string may appear later in the file". I will take it down and up vote ysth's answer